# Gatsby createPage Actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

This is my gatsby-node.js file.  I am attempting to get my gatsby program to dynamically create pages for each user in my api with the path being node.example.  I'm currently running a local dev environment and I am getting my data from a local json server.  It appears that a page is only being created for the users that I manually place a "path" field with "/example" in their corresponding json element.  Also, in graphiQL, it is only returning data for the users that have an "ID" field when I call allRestApiEmployees.  Any idea on how to fix this?

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  //this is going to be referencing fields.js - not that specific node
  const profileTemplate = path.resolve("src/components/layout.js")

  //query to return user data
  return graphql(`
  {
      allRestApiEmployees {
          edges {
              node {
                  example
              }
            }
        }
  }
`).then(res => {
    if (res.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(res.errors)
    }
    res.data.allRestApiEmployees.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        var path = "/" + node.example
        console.log(node.example)
        createPage({
          path,
          component: profileTemplate,
        })
      })
  }) 
}
```

Comment: All types implementing the `Node` GraphQL Interface must have an `id` field of type `ID`. If you're not providing one when you create the nodes (e.g. in the owner of `allRestApiEmployees`), they may be getting dropped.

Comment: you can fork source plugin (https://github.com/danspratling/gatsby-source-multi-api/blob/master/src/gatsby-node.js) and modify `processResult` to construct id from other fields